# Возможно ли получить из TextView, первую видимою строку вверху экрана?

Tags: android, android-textview, scrollview

Создаю приложение для чтение книги.
Я хочу реализовать закладки.

В ScrollView находится TextView, содержащий главу из книги.

Возможно ли получить из TextView, первую видимою строку вверху экрана?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например можно получить строку (не важно какую) исходя из кол-ва строк в виджете:

```
Layout layout = textView.getLayout();
String text = textView.getText().toString();
int start=0;
int end;
for (int i=0; i<textView.getLineCount(); i++) {
    end = layout.getLineEnd(i);
    line[i] = text.substring(start,end);
    start = end;
}
```

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272614/how-do-i-get-the-text-at-a-specific-line-in-a-textview) также подобный вопрос.